# Perform a repeated click on an element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've located the elements I need in a webpage, and called them each something appropriate.  Is there a way to just call the element by name later in the test script and click it, without having to locate the element again?

Tried splitting the find_element_by/.click() into two separate lines, so I know it can reference the name I've assigned to the element.

```
costs = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('g:nth-child(2) > g > circle')
costs.click()

revenue = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#chart-div-2 g:nth-child(1) > rect')
revenue.click()
```

(then after these steps and a few similar, I've tried adding in....)

```
costs.click()
revenue.click()
```

Message:

> 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document', but I've not navigated away from the page.

What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to refer to them again since the element is stale.

So in your case:

```
costs = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('g:nth-child(2) > g > circle')
costs.click()
revenue = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#chart-div-2 g:nth-child(1) > rect')
revenue.click()

# DO SOME STUFF

costs = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('g:nth-child(2) > g > circle')
costs.click()
revenue = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#chart-div-2 g:nth-child(1) > rect')
revenue.click()
```

Read more about [Stale Element Reference Exception](http://allselenium.info/handle-stale-element-reference-exception-python-selenium/).